Java 21 Create StructuredTaskScope from ExecutorService
Fine, this is most probably a silly question...
Is there a way to construct a StructuredTaskScope using an ExecutorService?
Any idea is welcome.
Best regards
Alex

The only thing I could find was a custom ThreadFactory. Officially that should create new threads, but you could possibly write your own implementation that can reuse threads. That's not compatible with ExecutorService though.

Its not clear what you are asking - edit question. StructuredTaskScope has 2 constructors (presently), neither of which accept ExecutorService.

Right, there is no Constructor accepting an ExecutorService.
Should've phrased it more clearly: Is there a way to create a StructuredTaskScope using an ExecutorService?
I would like to avoid to rewrite a lot of things. I'm lazy.   =P
